# Method POST is not supported for this route

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am using `Laravel v6.18.22` I can successfully insert and edit `staff records`, using jquery and ajax! The problem is after click `submit` om the modal form, I can insert data or edit successfully but after any of those operation, the `modal hided` and i get a `success message`i use `sweetalert`, but the browser keeps loading and end up throwing that error! `The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.`

**How do i solve this issue, things are working as i am expecting then afterwards error ruins everything**

**Ajax code-update**

```
 $(function () {
        $('#addStaffForm').on('submit', function (e) {
           if(!e.isDefaultPrevented()){
               let id = $('#id').val();
               if(save_method === 'add') {
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: 'registerStaff',
                       data: new FormData($('#addStaffForm')[0]),
                       contentType: false,
                       processData: false,
                       success: function(data) {
                           $('#addStaff').modal('hide');
                           table.ajax.reload();
                           Swal.fire({
                               title: 'Success',
                               text: 'Staff Registered Successfully',
                               icon: 'success',
                           });
                       },
                       error: function (data) {
                           Swal.fire({
                               title: 'Error',
                               text: 'Staff registration failed',
                               icon: 'error',
                           });
                       }
                   })
               }else {
                  
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: 'updateStaff/' + id,
                       data: new FormData($('#addStaffForm')[0]),
                       contentType: false,
                       processData: false,
                       headers: {
                           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                       },
                       success: function(data) {
                           $('#addStaff').modal('hide');
                           table.ajax.reload();
                           Swal.fire({
                               title: 'Success',
                               text: 'Staff Updated Successfully',
                               icon: 'success',
                           });
                       },
                       error: function (data) {
                           Swal.fire({
                               title: 'Error',
                               text: 'Staff Update failed',
                               icon: 'error',
                           });
                       }
                   })
               }

           }

        })
    });
```

**Routes**

```
Route::post('updateStaff/{id}', 'StaffController@updateStaffInfo');
Route::post('registerStaff', ['as'=> 'register_staff', 'uses' => 'StaffController@registerStaff']);
```

**Form**

```
<form method="post" id="addStaffForm" data-toggle="validator">
            <div class="modal-body">
                @csrf
                @method('POST')
                <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{__('Staff Name')}}</label>
                    <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required  autofocus>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{__('Email Address')}} </label>
                    <input required id="email" type="email" class="form-control " name="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label >{{__('Password')}} </label>
                    <input required value="12345678" readonly id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                    <span class="text-info" role="alert"><strong>{{__('Default Password 12345678')}}</strong></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{__('Confirm Password')}} </label>
                    <input  readonly type="password" id="confirm_password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" value="12345678" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{ __('Position') }} </label>
                    <select required id="role_id" type="select" class="form-control" name="role_id">
                        @if($roles->count() > 0)
                            @foreach ($roles as $role)
                                <option value="{{$role->id}}">{{$role->role_name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" id="insertBtn" class="btn btn-info"></button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**Network Tab in google chrome**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3gxr.png)

Comment: Can you update your question with the request headers from the network tab in chrome when you are submitting the form.

Comment: Firstly you don't need define `@method('POST')` in add form. Secondly, change your update route `::post` to `::put`. Thirdly add `csrf token` to your ajax code in add method.

Comment: Everything looks correct to me, so it seems likely that your routes are being cached. So you can try ```php artisan route:clear```.

Comment: @xNoJustice ```@method('POST')``` is unnecessary as you noted, but wont cause this issue. same with having the ```@csrf``` token in the form.  But you are correct that he forgot the csrf in the registerStaff ajax call. Also, I agree ```PUT``` is better for the update route semantically but wont fix the issue.

Comment: @KurtFriars, I have tried all tips as you have suggested above, but i still get the error! please check the image i have attached of the network tab in chrome, for the request headers! Perphaps the issue originated there

Comment: @Mathew I was not making any recommendations, I was commenting on NoJustice's. I don't care to see the laravel error page, please show the headers IN the network tab request.

Comment: Also, from what I can see you are posting to showstaff. So you are likely not preventing the submit button from bubbling. I will make an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the submit event from being handled, it is trying to post to the current page's url, not the route in in your ajax call.:

```
$(function () {
    $('#addStaffForm').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
           
        let id = $('#id').val();
           
        if(save_method === 'add') {
            ...
```